# What is the dual of norm function in form $\|x-y\|$?

Tags: normed-spaces, duality-theorems

I want to get the dual of the following norm function:

$$\max_\alpha\sum_i \alpha_i \|\lambda_i - \sum_j \alpha_j \lambda_j \|^2$$

And I know that the dual of this function is:

$$\min_\alpha \sum_i \sum_j \alpha_i \alpha_j \lambda_i \lambda_j - \sum_i \alpha_i \lambda_i^2 \quad \text{s.t.}\quad \sum_i \alpha_i = 1$$

Can someone explain how I can get this dual form?

Source: *Ben-Hur, Asa; Horn, David; Siegelmann, Hava T.; Vapnik, Vladimir*, [**Support vector clustering**](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v2/horn01a.html), J. Mach. Learn. Res. 2, No. 2, 125-137 (2002). [ZBL1002.68598](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1002.68598).